# Win 10 + Symfony 4 + MSSQL error Attempted to call function "sqlsrv_configure" from global namespace

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to connect S4 to MS SQL-server. I tried with php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll driver but I get : "Attempted to call function "sqlsrv_configure" from the global namespace."
I tried then with the php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll driver but i've got the same error...
It's not really clear for me how to proceed in S4 : this is what i did :

- I edited .env and added 'DATABASE_URL=sqlsrv://user:password@11.10.10.109:14331/EDC'
- I created the Entity src/Entity/TAVISDECES.php
- Then in the code I'm doing :

  $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM App\Entity\TAVISDECES u ');

  $results= $query->getResult();

but it fires the above message, no matter which driver I'm using...
Did I miss smth ?
Any idea welcome

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trials, I think it was a problem of driver : in my case (WIN 10)  the good one was :
php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll